# Is there an auto generated template for documenting function or class in eclipse?

Tags: android, visual-studio, eclipse

In visual studio,  I can type in ///  and visual studio will auto generate the following lines for documentation purposes.

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

Is there something similar in eclipse for ADT?  If there is how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some automation to generate javadocs (e.g., keystrokes like: `/** <enter>` or `<shift><alt> J`)

You can check some online tutorials about javadoc+Eclipse:

- http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/~billard/se/cs3340/ex7/javadoctutorial.html
- http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/javadoc/
- http://eclipseone.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/add-comments-and-javadocs-in-eclipse-with-a-single-keystroke/
- http://www.eclipse-blog.org/eclipse-ide/generating-javadoc-in-eclipse-ide.html

And plugins like:

- http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/
- http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/eclipse/javadoc.html